# UINT datatype of C++ Equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, c++, types, typeconverter

I have structure in C++. How to convert the structure to C#.

**C++ structure**

```
typedef struct test
{
short test_limit;
UINT match_number;
float version;
char unused;
}TEST_LAYOUT;
```

I just tried to convert the struct. but the UINT data type, I'm not sure what to use.

Comment: Please show your C# struct.

Comment: Assuming Windows and the [common Windows types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types) then `UINT` is an unsigned `INT`. And `INT` is a (signed) 32-bit integer type. Unless the range is important, any unsigned integer type is suitable in the C# Code.

Comment: My C# structure definition is:
public struct test
{
short test_limit;
uint match_number;
float version;
char unused;
}

Answer (score 2):

Find out what UINT is. (google to the rescue)
Assuming you're on Windows UINT is probably just `typedef unsigned int UINT;` Which is a unsigned 32bit integer.

Now search "c# unsigned 32 bit integer" -> `uint`